# What advantages does the Analogue Super Nt have over an original SNES console?

Tags: snes, analogue-super-nt

I was looking to buy the Analouge Super Nt console, but I just came across to an original Super Nintendo console in great condition.

I have a modern Full HD TV but it still has RCA input, so I can connect the original SNES without a problem, right? Or do I still need some kind of converter?

Is there any other reason why I should consider the Analogue over an original SNES?

Comment: This isn't shopping rec. *"When it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy."* -  from the [Q&A Is Hard](//stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog in the close reason. A good answer to this would outline differences between the two devices, their pros and cons, and other considerations like clone-console accuracy & failing components on 30 y/o hardware. That is not a 'list of products matching criteria'. Just because a question uses the word 'buy' does not make it a 'shopping rec'.